# How to get file count as zero with recursive directory search?

Tags: python, file, directory

I am trying to get a file count for a particular filename match and write to a dictionary. The below code works fine if all directories contain some files (match or no match). However, if there is an empty directory, it is not shown in the dictionary. Folder2 is empty and is not shown in the result.
I would also like to know if there is a way to print the result with one forward slash separator instead of combination of double back and forward slashes? 
My code:

```
import os
import re
def file_count_search(root_dir,keyword):
    dict={}
    for dirpath,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(root_dir,topdown=True):
        matches = re.findall(keyword, str(filenames))
        if keyword in matches:
            dict[os.path.join(root_dir,dirpath)] = len(matches)
    print dict
file_count_search("c://test","file")
```

My Result:

```
{
    'c://test\\folder3\\subdir_folder3': 1, 
    'c://test': 1, 'c://test\\folder1': 3,
    'c://test\\folder3': 1
}
```

Desired Result:

```
{
    'c:/test/folder3/subdir_folder3': 1,
    'c:/test': 1, 'c:/test/folder1': 3,
    'c:/test/folder2': 0,
    'c:/test/folder3': 1
}
```

Comment: `dict` is a reserved keyword and you shouldn't use it as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. Noted not to use reserved keywords as variable name. I still look forward to a solution of showing count as 0 if the folder is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no matching files in a given directory, `matches` will be an empty list, so `keyword in matches` will evaluate to `False`, and nothing will be added to `dict`.

Try replacing this line:

```
if keyword in matches:
  dict[os.path.join(root_dir,dirpath)] = len(matches)
```

with just this (also replacing `dict` with a non-reserved variable name per Dan Farrell's note):

```
path_to_match_count[os.path.join(root_dir,dirpath)] = len(matches)
```

... for an update script like this:

```
import os
import re
def file_count_search(root_dir,keyword):
    path_to_match_count={}
    for dirpath,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(root_dir,topdown=True):
        matches = re.findall(keyword, str(filenames))
        path_to_match_count[os.path.join(root_dir,dirpath)] = len(matches)
    print path_to_match_count
file_count_search("c://test","file")
```

Comment: Yes, I figured if keyword in matches: condition is not the correct one to use. I am looking for a better approach that could solve the issue

Comment: @Sel_Python can you help me better understand the issue you still need solved? Is it simply having `/` instead of `\\` as the delimiter?

Comment: Ah.. I had not noticed that the 'if' condition was taken out in the solution provided. Thank you, your suggestion worked.
Yes, it still shows double backslashes instead of single forward slash but that is cosmetic. Thought os.sep (or something similar) would work but no luck yet. 
my result shows:
{'C:/test': 1, 'C:/test\\folder3\\subdir_folder3': 1, 'C:/test\\folder1': 3, 'C:/test\\folder3': 1, 'C:/test\\folder2': 0}

Comment: Ah, I could have made what I changed clearer. Updated the answer for clarity. Regarding the backslashes, I think that's just Windows path notation, with the backslash escape character itself escaped in the printed representation. You could always `split` it and `join` with another separator, but there's probably not much value to that.